# Why is Firebase returning deleted account?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I deleted an account from Firebase and it does not show in the Authentication section of my Firebase console. However, when I rerun my program it still gives me the user id of the deleted account.

This how I get my current user.

```
  Future<FirebaseUser> GetCurrentUser()async{
    FirebaseUser user= await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    print(user.uid);
    return (user != null) ? user : null;
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete a user account in the console, it doesn't automatically out to client apps to tell them the user is deleted.  The user token in the app is still valid for up to one hour after the token was generated.  From the app's perspective, the user still appears signed in.  The user doesn't fully sign out until until the Firebase Auth SDK tries to refresh that token.  This occurs automatically before the hour is up, or until your code tries to refresh manually.

Comment: do you know how can I refresh my code automatically when an account is deleted?

Comment: You could arrange for a push notification to be sent to the device somehow to tell it what to do.  There is no easy way.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try an onAuthStateChanged feature.

Comment: That won't pick up the change. If you want to manually refresh, you can do that by using getIdToken(true), but it will not happen automatically. https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser/getIdToken.html